# What are the ports needs to be opened for NTPD?

Tags: linux, firewall, ntpd

Having `port 123/UDP` outbound but getting an error mentioned below.

```
ntpdate -q 0.rhel.pool.ntp.org
server 173.255.215.209, stratum 0, offset 0.000000, delay 0.00000
27 Sep 03:51:46 ntpdate[39518]: no server suitable for synchronization found
```

Comment: `getent services ntp`

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to run ntpd , you need to fix your network/firewall/NAT so that ntpd can have full unrestricted access to UDP port 123 in both directions.

Comment: I have Configured NTP Client to Synchronize with NTP Server(0.rhel.pool.ntp.org). for that what are ports need to be opened?

Comment: @EBINGLADSON the answer tells you this - _unrestricted access to UDP port 123 in both directions_.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how other folks feels about this but IMHO `ntp` is a bad implementation. It drives me nuts to see a NTP clients with open **incomming** ports.
**Besides** it's unclear what that incomming port is actually used for in the `ntp` implementation since there seems to be confusion out there if it has to be open at all if trying only to sync local time with a remote NTP server (aka "client only" mode). I have not looked through the source to find the correct answer to that question but the fact that this port is opend by default itself makes me not want to review that codebase.

You should consider using `openntpd` or `chrony` instead. Both don't require incomming ports and the configuration can be done in a single, self-explaining config file.

My general advice would be to **not** use the `ntp` implementation whenever possible and replace it with those alternatives. Let's hope `ntp` get's some serious updates to fix those crazy requirements or get's replaced by some other implementation by default really soon.

Comment: If you use NTP as a client only, you only need to open UDP/123 for **incoming** traffic **if** your firewall is not doing connection tracking for the NTP protocol specifically. If you're using Linux `iptables` and your ruleset has `iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` or similar near the beginning, you're fine without opening UDP/123 for incoming traffic, since `iptables` connection tracking understands NTP. A different firewall implementation might require opening incoming UDP/123 so that answers to your outgoing queries can get back to you.

Comment: But why does it need incomming traffic at all? What's wrong about running in pull mode?

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol: unless the firewall knows about NTP specifically, it won't be able to tell between legitimate responses and random other incoming packets. If dealing with such a firewall, if you don't allow for incoming NTP packets on UDP/123, you can pull all you want but you just won't **get** any answers - the firewall will just drop them all. NTP cannot use TCP because TCP's error detection would introduce delays and re-transmissions - and inserting unpredictable variable delays to a time signal will make it useless.

Comment: While I understand the udp implications you pointed out I now wonder how openntpd and others are working just fine without the need for this.

Comment: I would guess that "openntpd and others" are new enough so that they have been used mostly with new firewalls that have NTP connection tracking as a matter of course. The advice to open incoming UDP/123 for the classic `ntpd` originates from an older time when firewalls did not have that feature as standard, and sometimes that now-obsolete advice is blindly repeated (even in some books!) without the background knowledge of exactly why and when it's needed and when it's not.

Comment: Not sure if that's all to it. The documentation of openntpd states that by default (client mode) it doesn't listen to any ports.

Comment: You cannot receive an UDP packet (e.g. an answer to a NTP request) without opening a port. But when there is no need to serve any clients, the port can be open only for as long as it takes to receive the answer from the queried NTP server. On a good connection this can easily be less than 20 milliseconds on each poll interval (64 seconds or more in classic NTP), so it can be kind of hard to notice (and also hard to attack): the port is open only 1/3200 of the time, and the software will discard anything that does not look like a valid answer to the request it made anyway.

Comment: Would have to need to look up the source to verify but I guess you're right. Anything else would mean changes to the NTP protocol which obviously is not the case with openntpd since it doesn't relay on a specific NTP implementation. However: you just verified my initial opinion that `ntpd` is a rather bad implementation since as far as I remember with it the port stays open 24/7.

Comment: Yeah, the classic ntpd acts as a server by default, you have to take specific configuration steps to make it reject potential clients, and even if you set its security rules to "absolutely ignore anything incoming that is not a response to outgoing query", the port stays open always. It's a product of a different, older, more trusting early age of the internet.

Comment: I adopted my initial post to be less harsh on `ntpd`. Thinking about how cricital stuff like NTP and DNS have become I still believe it's important to move forward and security and user friendly handling certainly are very important design aspects today. Anyway: thanks for the discussion. In special the UDP part (that I totally did not think about when writing my answer) was interesting to me.